# What is the reason gravitational waves propagate at speed of light?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

I know Maxwell equation shows that it is the electric and magnetic properties of empty space which is why speed of light is constant, but what about [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave)? I have visited many answers but so far none seems satisfactory to me. Can we prove that gravitational wave is also a constant?

Comment: It's part of the general relativity theory. This Wikipedia article might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_gravity (including linked articles or references, if you want more)

Comment: You'll find this in any GR book. We use an ansatz $h^{ab} = A^{ab}\exp(ik_ax^a)$ and substituting this into the linearised equation we find $\mathbf k$ is a null one-form i.e. the wave travels at $c$.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I can't find the equation but is it the rate of energy loss due to inspiral of compact stars.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254628/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255361/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @user6760 the equation for the power emitted as gravitational waves is given in my answer to [Is it possible to produce gravitational waves artificially?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187947/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because gravitational waves are massless. Special relativity states that massless matter moves at $c$ in vacuum.

Comment: How do you manage to post an answer after this question was closed! What socery is this? ;D

Comment: Just luck, I think. That and the answer is correct!